# Modulus in django query

Tags: python, mysql, django

How would I do the following SQL in the django ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM main_titlemaster WHERE id % 4 = 0
```

The model name is `TitleMaster`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.extra()`:

```
TitleMaster.objects.extra(where=['id mod 4=0'])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: For anyone arriving here, considering using this solution: The docs do no recommend using it.

> This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model), the correct way of doing this today is using an `F()` expression:

> Django supports the use of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulo, and power arithmetic with F() objects

This should do the trick:

```
TitleMaster.objects.annotate(mod_four=F("id") % 4).filter(mod_four=0)
```